# Allow site members to create public views

Tags: permissions, view

As a site owner, I can create views and mark them as 'public' - however site members can't (by default).

How do I add this particular capability to a group?  I don't want them to be able to change the default view.. Just for them to be able to share views that they have created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Management of public views requires the Manage List permission. You can create a custom permission level or use one of the out-of-the-box permission levels that includes the Manage List permission: Full Control, Design, Manage Hierarchy are a few

Keep in mind that Manage List also enables users to manage list columns or delete the list altogether

Comment: It was actually a document library, is that the same?  So if this permission is granted, the user can delete the entire library?  Don't think we want that!

Comment: Same thing... Manage List also exposes the ability to delete a list and manage list columns.